# Combining Manipulate and NDEigenvalues

Tags: graphics, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-value

I think there may be a quick solution to this problem which I can't seem to fix at the moment. The question is how do we eliminate the error in the following

```
\[ScriptCapitalL] = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]; 
\[ScriptCapitalB] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True]; 
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[NDEigenvalues[{\[ScriptCapitalL], \[ScriptCapitalB]}, 
   u[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {u, v}]], 
   2]], {u, 2, 4}, {v, 5, 8}]
```

Briefly I am trying to examine the effect of the radii (as quantified by `u` and `v`) on the `NDEigenvalues`. The error I get is

```
(* The temporal variable (NDSolve`NDEigensystemDump`t) can not be found in the PDE operator. >>*)
```

The code gives the expected answers if `Manipulate` is discarded, and I just use `ListPlot & Table` tools. So why the complication when `Manipulate` is included?

Comment: You're using the symbols `u` and `v` for two conflicting things. In `NDEigenvalues`,  `u` is the unknown function, and at the same time it's used as a radius in `SphericalShell`. You should just rename the `Manipulate` variables to something else, e.g., `u1` and `v1`.

Comment: @Jens  it works following your suggestion. Thanks